# Shall used in the first person future tense (I believe...?)

Tags: will-shall

Would it be correct to say,

> "Well then, I shall be on with it, now shalt I".

Comment: "I shalt" or "shalt I" is never correct.  *Shalt* is only for the second person singular.  Besides that, *shalt* is extremely old-fashioned.  Don't use it unless you are trying to talk like a seventeenth-century Bible.

Comment: If you really need the confirmation at the end, you could use "Well then, I shall be on with it, *I will*". Not a usual usage, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty old-fashioned, but sure. More modernly, you could try "Well, then, I'll get on with it."

Don't use "shalt." I don't know Early Modern English well enough to be sure if that is proper usage, but I bet it isn't, because it sounds wrong. Ending with "I shall be on with it" is perfectly fine.